# How to implement Dependencies Injection in abstract class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an abstract class `Validation`, which got further extending `TextLetterValidation` and `TextNullValidation`. My question is, how to use and implement dependency injection?

### interface

```
 public interface IValidation
{
    bool Validate(string text);
}
```

### Abstract class

```
 public abstract class Validation : IValidation
{
    public abstract bool Validate(string text);
}
```

### text Letter validation

```
 public class TextLetterValidation : Validation
{
    public override bool Validate(string text)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    }
}
```

### Text null validation

```
 public class TextNullValidation: Validation
{
    public override bool Validate(string text)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

my question is how to implement above in my class?

### My class

```
public class xyz: AppAmbientState, IPalindrome
{
    private readonly IValidation _validation;

    public xyz(IValidation validation)
    {
        _validation = validation;
    }

    bool IPalindrome.IsTextValid { get; set; }

    public bool IsTextPalindrome(string text)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ValidateText(string text)
    {

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You will need to clarify what it is you are asking as it is currently unclear.

Comment: First you need to inherit the abstract class to your class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that depends what you try to achiev

if you need to provide specific implementation of `IValidation` then register it like this:

```
services.AddTransient<TextNullValidation>();
services.AddTransient<TextLetterValidation>();
services.AddTransient<Func<string, IValidation>>(sp => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "TextNullValidation":
            return sp.GetService<TextNullValidation>();
        case "TextLetterValidation":
            return sp.GetService<TextLetterValidation>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});
```

and use factory where you inject interface

```
private readonly IValidation _validation;

public Test(Func<string, IValidation> validationFactory)
{
    // will provide TextNullValidation instance
    _validation = validationFactory("TextNullValidation"); 
}
```

or register both:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidation, TextNullValidation>();
services.AddTransient<IValidation, TextLetterValidation>();
```

and change code so you have access to each implementation

```
private readonly ICollection<IValidation> _validation;

public xyz(ICollection<IValidation> validation)
{
    _validation = validation;
}
```